# Choosing between Bull queue and Database Triggers

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, triggers, queue

I have a use case where I have to create a record in the database for users repeatedly on a scheduled basis. Let's say every Monday Weekly/BiWeekly. There are two ways with which i can achieve it.

1. Using Database Triggers to Create a record on the time. But I don't know how to repeat it. I have to create a trigger for the next schedule when this trigger runs, which i don't think is right approach.
2. Using Queues to handle the scheduling and executing the repeated jobs. But adding a job for each user is not a good idea I guess. I might be wrong but there is no other way to achieve my goal.

I am confused on what to choose between the two. Let's say i have to do this for 1 million users every week Monday at 9.00 a.m.

Which approach will scale?

I am using nodejs as my backend and using Bull-Queue for the queue and postgres as my Database.

Comment: Sounds like a *batch job* scheduled by `cron` that processes all users in one go.

Comment: The Problem with this is I will have to edit the job's data dynamically. The usecase could be removing a single user from the cron which has all my user objects.

Comment: That would be a configuration table that contains the users to be processed by the batch job. You add and remove users as required.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be the efficient degin. Please post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using Database Triggers to Create a record on the time. But I don't
>   know how to repeat it. I have to create a trigger for the next
>   schedule when this trigger runs, which i don't think is right
>   approach.
>    - Not a right approach based on the so many factors like - memory, number of requests and code quality.

So I went with the second approach:

> Using Queues to handle the scheduling and executing the repeated jobs.
>   But adding a job for each user is not a good idea I guess. I might be
>   wrong but there is no other way to achieve my goal.